# Don't render HTML element, if DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "someValue") == 0

Tags: asp.net, asprepeater

I have a `<asp:repeater>` inside which i'm rendering a table with a few rows.
Each row - corresponding to a different value.

Question: how to "skip" the row, in case this value is empty?

here is evaluation statement:

```
<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Website") == ""? "" : /*render element*/ %>
```

and here is element i want to render in case statement if false:

```
<tr>
    <td><span>Website address:</span></td>
    <td>
        <p><a href="<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Website") %>" class="red-link"><%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Website") %></a></p>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<asp:Repeater runat="server" id="myRepeater">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <tr runat="server" 
           visible='<%#String.Format("{0}",DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Website"))!="" %>'>
            <td><span>Website address:</span></td>
            <td>
                <p><a href='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Website") %>" 
                    class="red-link'><%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Website") %></a></p>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

It will set the row's `visible` attribute to `false` when the `Website` is empty or `null`.

Comment: This one throws "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" for "<tr runat="server" " row.

Comment: What is the datasource for the control?

Comment: Datasource is the list of objects. This repeater works perfect, but the only thing i need - to not render table row for certain item property, if it's value is "empty"

Comment: I don't know why, but that suddenly begun working properly, in a way as you proposed. But it still stays a mystery for me, why it didn't worked previous 2-3 copy/pastes

Comment: Unless you're stuck with ASP.NET 1.0, you can replace `string.Format("{0}", DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Website"))` with: `Eval("Website", "{0}")`, which will achieve the same thing.